# Openning encrypted realm created using NOT iOS Realm SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, encryption, realm

I want to use pre-filled encrypted realm db in my iOS Application. I tried to put it in Bundle and then to read it. It works well if I will use NOT encrypted realm DB, but if I use encrypted app can't open realm.

I tried to create pre-filled encrypted realm db using my own Mac app and using node.js sdk. In both cases iOS app can't open and decrypt realm. Without encryption everything works perfect.

If then I will try to open this realm file using Realm browser everything will open! I am sure that realm is encrypted, because Realm Browser asks me for the key. I entered it and it works.

What is interesting is that encrypted realm is easily can be read by simulator but not the real device.

### Goals

To make Swift Realm working with encrypted realm files created using not iOS sdk.

### Actual Results

> Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/73CBF3CD-1E1E-4C7B-85E3-607D20217DCC/app-app.app/config.realm':
>   Realm file decryption failed." UserInfo={Error Code=2,
>   NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/73CBF3CD-1E1E-4C7B-85E3-607D20217DCC/app-app.app/config.realm,
>   Underlying=Realm file decryption failed, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable
>   to open a realm at path
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/73CBF3CD-1E1E-4C7B-85E3-607D20217DCC/app-app.app/config.realm':
>   Realm file decryption failed.}

### Code Sample

```
let encryptionConfig = Realm.Configuration(
            fileURL: pathToRealmInBundle,
            encryptionKey: encryptionKey,
            readOnly: true,
            objectTypes: [
                ...
            ]
        )
        guard let realm = try? Realm(configuration: encryptionConfig) else {
            print("Fail")
            return nil
        }
```

### Version of Realm and Tooling

Realm framework version: 3.0.2

Xcode version: Version 9.1 (9B55)

iOS/OSX version: 
iPhone 6 iOS 11.1.2

Dependency manager + version: 
Pod 1.3.1